# Countif in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, countif

I have a table in Power BI and looking to create a measure similar to Countif in Excel to count if Audit Rating contains Pass.

I have tried the below DAX but is failing as filter requires two arguments.

```
Pass Count = CALCULATE(COUNT('Export'[Audit Rating]),FILTER('Export'[Audit Rating] = "Pass"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You came very close: Try this one:

```
Pass Count =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'Export'[Audit Rating] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Export'[Audit Rating] ), 'Export'[Audit Rating] = "Pass" )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just couldn't figure out what to do for 2nd argument, but your answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. It happens sometimes. Next time you know what to do! Good Luck!